# Showing zero results while search on files in note pad ++

Tags: full-text-search, notepad++

Every time Showing zero results while search on files in Notepad++:

[image]

Thanks !!

Comment: Are you sure there are `.js` files in the given directory and `js` files contain `directive` word? Because same thing working for me and I can see this working in your screenshot too for keyword `equal`

Comment: This issue solved after updating new version of notepadd++ .yes ! i am searching in js files .